# Java compare integer and bigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger, bigint

How do I compare an `int` with a `BigInteger` in Java? I specifically need the know if an `int` is less than a `BigInteger`. Here is the code I am using:

```
private static BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
private static BigInteger three = new BigInteger("3");
private static BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0");    
public static BigInteger bigIntSqRootCeil(BigInteger x) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (x.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative argument.");
    }
    if (x == BigInteger.ZERO || x == BigInteger.ONE) {
        return x;
    }
    BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2L);
    BigInteger y;
    for (y = x.divide(two);
            y.compareTo(x.divide(y)) > 0;
            y = ((x.divide(y)).add(y)).divide(two));
    if (x.compareTo(y.multiply(y)) == 0) {
        return y;
    } else {
        return y.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
}
private static boolean isPrimeBig(BigInteger n){
    if (n.mod(two) == zero)
        return (n.equals(two));
    if (n.mod(three) == zero)
        return (n.equals(three));
    BigInteger m = bigIntSqRootCeil(n);
    for (int i = 5; i <= m; i += 6) {
        if (n.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(i)) == zero)
            return false;
        if(n.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(i + 2)) == zero)
            return false;
    };
    return true;
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, why do you think that isn't working?

Comment: @E_net4 Um... I know why it isn't working. I am looking for a solution.

Comment: That is a LOT of code if what you're asking for is "compare BigInt with an int".  Is there another question hidden in there?  Otherwise: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo(java.math.BigInteger) `compareTo` returns -1 (less than), 0 (equal), or 1 (greater than)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> How do I compare an int with a BigInteger in Java? I specifically need the know if an int is less than a BigInteger.

Turn the `int` into a `BigInteger` before comparing:

```
if (BigInteger.valueOf(intValue).compareTo(bigIntegerValue) < 0) {
  // intValue is less than bigIntegerValue
}
```

Comment: +1 for casting the int into a BigInt, vs the other way around.  Might want to mention why

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
if (x == BigInteger.ZERO || x == BigInteger.ONE) {
    return x;
```

You should use :-

```
if (x.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || x.equals(BigInteger.ONE)){
return x;
```

Also, you should change the Integer first to BigInteger, and then compare, as mentioned by [`Joe`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/733345/joe) in his answer:

```
 Integer a=3;
 if(BigInteger.valueOf(a).compareTo(BigInteger.TEN)<0){
    // your code...
 }
 else{
    // your rest code, and so on.
 }
```

Comment: Although it is an issue in the question's code snippet, that doesn't really answer the main question.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `BigInteger.compare`:

```
int myInt = ...;
BigInteger myBigInt = ...;
BigInteger myIntAsABigInt = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(myInt));

if (myBigInt.compareTo(myIntAsABigInt) < 0) {
    System.out.println ("myInt is bigger than myBigInt");
} else if (myBigInt.compareTo(myIntAsABigInt) > 0) {
    System.out.println ("myBigInt is bigger than myInt");
} else {
    System.out.println ("myBigInt is equal to myInt");
}
```