# using biginteger for java program regarding virtual addresses

Tags: java, virtual, biginteger

Maybe I'm misunderstanding due to my limited use of biginteger, but I have a program that needs to take user input for page size and virtual address and calculate offset and virtual page. I can do the calculation no problem, but when comparing itegers for the input, the necessary value of virtual address ( 4294967295)is out of range. I tried to declare this number as a big int but the same operators don't seem to work. Do I have to forget the zero and just find a way to say the input is less than or equal to this number? Here is the code:

```
public class VAddress {

public static void main(String args[]){

    BigInteger max = new BigInteger("4294967295"); 

    Scanner PAGEinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner ADDinput = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please Enter the system page size (between 512 and 16384):");
    int page = PAGEinput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please Enter the Virtual Address: ");
    int address = ADDinput.nextInt();

    if(page >= 512 && page <= 16384){
        if( address >= 0 && address <= max){

        }
       }



     }

 }
```

Comment: Have you considered usage of `long`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BigInteger address = new BigInteger(address);
if(page >= 512 && page <= 16384){
    if(address.compareTo(new BigInteger("0"))>=0 && address.compareTo(max)<=0){

    }
}
```

Comment: Though as many people will point out, long primitive type can hold the value and you can just use that instead.

Comment: perfect, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't using too much unnecessary syntax. Thanks everybody!

Comment: `compareTo(new BigInteger("0"))` is equivalent to `signum()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the integer `address` into a BigInteger as well so that you can compare it to max, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824764/java-compare-integer-and-biginteger)

Comment: So something similar to this:    System.out.println("Please Enter the Virtual Address: ");
  BigInteger address = ADDinput.nextBigInteger();

Comment: yup. Don't forget to cast the 0 as biginteger too if you go this route